# Geometric interpretation of algebraic property

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, modules, algebraic-curves

Let $X \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be an irreducible affine algebraic curve with coordinate ring $$\mathbb{C}[X] = \mathbb{C}[z_1, \ldots, z_n] / (f_1, \ldots, f_m ) $$ with each $f_i \in \mathbb{Z}[z_1, \ldots, z_n]$.  Define $\mathbb{Z}[X] = \mathbb{Z}[z_1, \ldots, z_n] / (f_1, \ldots, f_m )$.

Now, if $f\in \mathbb{C}[X]$ can be represented by a polynomial in with integer coefficients, then $\mathbb{C}[X]$ (resp. $\mathbb{Z}[X]$) can be regarded as a module over $\mathbb{C}[f]$ (resp. $\mathbb{Z}[f]$), where $\mathbb{C}[f]$ is the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra generated by $f$ in $\mathbb{C}[X]$.  Note that $\mathbb{C}[f]$ is the image of the induced homomorphims $f^\ast \colon \mathbb{C}[\mathbb{A}^1] \to \mathbb{C}[X]$.

Suppose $\mathbb{C}[X]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ are finitely generated over $\mathbb{C}[f]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[f]$ (i.e. $f$ is a finite regular map).  For $\mathbb{S} \in \{ \mathbb{C, Z}\}$, let $\mu_\mathbb{S} (f)$ denote the minimal number of generators for $\mathbb{S}[X]$ over $\mathbb{S}[f]$.  Then $\mu_\mathbb{Z}(f) \geq \mu_\mathbb{C} ( f)$ and this inequality can be strict.

My question:  Is there a geometric interpretation of the case when $\mu_\mathbb{Z} ( f) > \mu_\mathbb{C} (f)$?  What does this say about $f$ when thinking of it as a regular function on $X$?  Does this inequality tell us anything geometric about $X$?

Edit: From [this Overflow post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/29993/rank-of-a-module) and Corollary A3.3 in Eisenbud's *Commutative Algebra*, it appears that this has to do with algebraic vector bundles on $\mathbb{A}^1$, but I can't figure out how the regular function $f$ fits into the picture or what intersecting down to $\mathbb{Z}$ does.

Comment: What do you mean for $\mathbb{S}[f]$?

Comment: @Armandoj18eos I mean the $\mathbb{S}$-algebra generated by $f$ in $\mathbb{S}[X]$ for $\mathbb{S} \in \{ \mathbb{C}, \mathbb{Z} \}$.  I'll edit that into my question.